# Help with rewriting a simple statement using Logical Quantifiers.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

The question was to rewrite the statement "The equation $x^2=-1$ has no real solution in $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z$" using only logical quantifiers and the words "such that"

My incorrectly marked answer was $\forall x \in \Z$, $\nexists x \in \Z$ such that $x^2=-1$.

I've looked at it for a while and can't see what I've done wrong, can anyone help me out?

Comment: By `\Z` did you mean $\Bbb Z$, which is `\mathbb{Z}` or `\Bbb Z`?

Comment: The answer, by the way, is that you shouldn't have included anything to the left of $\not\exists$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I meant \mathbb{Z} looks like someone was nice enough to edit it for me though. Thanks for the answer, that makes sense now that I think about it

Answer (score 1):

This is how I translate it:

$(\lnot\exists x\in \mathbb{Z})$ such that [sometimes notated as $\ni$] $(x^2=-1)$

In you notation: $\forall x \in \mathbb Z,\lnot \exists x\in \mathbb Z \text{ such that }x^2=-1$ the universal does not make sense. In fact, I am having a hard time interpreting your notation: "For every integer there is no integer?"